# How to resolve? - Expected spy emit to have been called once. It was called 0 times error in Jamine

Tags: angular, jasmine, click

I'm getting this error:

> Expected spy emit to have been called once. It was called 0 times.

Below is my code:

spec.ts:

```
    it('trigget next button click', async(() => {
    
            const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginForm1Component);
            const component = fixture.componentInstance;
            component.validateUserRequest = {
                mobileNum: '05XXXXXXXX',
                txnType: '',
                email: '',
                emiratesId: ''
            };
            const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
            debugger;
            spyOn(component.validateLoginEvent, 'emit').and.callThrough();
            component.ngOnInit();
            const button = nativeElement.querySelector('#loginBtn');
    
            button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
            expect(fixture.componentInstance.templateService.validFormFlag).toBe(false);
          
            fixture.detectChanges();
           component.validate(fixture.componentInstance.templateService.validFormFlag);
            expect(component.validateLoginEvent.emit).toBeDefined();
            expect(component.validateLoginEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); 
            expect(component.validateLoginEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));
```

HTML:

```html
    <form class="transfer-form marginTop120" id="loginForm" #declarativeForm="ngForm">
        <error-component></error-component>
        <div class="form-group" id="email" class="email">
            <label for="mobileNumber" class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg" id="textformat">
                {{ 'LOGIN.ENTER_YOUR_MOBILE_NUMBER' | translate }}&nbsp;<span class="labelHint">(05XXXXXXXX)</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="mobileNumber" placeholder="05XXXXXXXX" [(ngModel)]="validateUserRequest.mobileNum" only-number maxlength="10" />
        </div>
        <div style="transform:scale(0.7);transform-origin:0;">
            <re-captcha [(ngModel)]="declarativeFormCaptchaValue" name="captcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" required></re-captcha>
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder loginStep1">
            <span class="desc-small fa-pull-left mt-2 requestedColor">
                {{ 'LOGIN.NOT_REGISTERED' | translate }}
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" routerLink="/{{ globalService.routerConst.REGISTER }}" routerLinkActive="active">{{ 'LOGIN.REGISTER_NOW' | translate }}</a>
            </span> {{declarativeFormCaptchaValue}}
            <a class="button btn-md btn-blue button-step-1 fa-pull-right new-button" id="loginBtn" href="javascript:void(0);" validateLoginDirective [ngClass]="{'disabled': !declarativeFormCaptchaValue && globalService.properties.CAPTCHA_ENABLE }" (click)="validate(this.templateService.validFormFlag)">
                {{ 'SHARED.NEXT' | translate }}
            </a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

component.ts:

```
    export class LoginForm1Component implements OnInit {
      @Input() validateUserRequest: ValidateUserRequest;
      @Output() validateLoginEvent = new EventEmitter();
      public declarativeFormCaptchaValue: any;
    
      constructor(
        public router: Router,
        public globalService: GlobalService,
        public templateService: TemplateService
      ) { }
    
      ngOnInit() { }
    
      validate(isValid: boolean) {
        if (isValid) {
          this.validateLoginEvent.emit();
        }
      }
    
      resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
        console.log(`Resolved captcha with response: ${captchaResponse}`);
      }
    }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please take time to say what you already tried. Ask a clear question with a question mark. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The code that I posted is the one that I have tried.

Comment: The error means `emit` was not called. And, considering this line: `expect(fixture.componentInstance.templateService.validFormFlag).toBe(false);` and `if (isValid) {`, I'm not sure why you're expecting it to have been called.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey.. I didnt realise that. Thank you very much